# Using webform variables

Tags: forms

I've this hook that gets submitted values from my form which as 2 select options elements and prints the 2 values submitted.

```
function modsubmit_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission)
{
$cont=0;
foreach($submission->data as $val) {
      $value = array_shift($submission->data);
        $value = array_shift($value['value']);
        $data[$cont] = $value;
        $cont=$cont+1;}
```

drupal_set_message("The value inserted was: {$data[0]},{data[1]}");
}
Now i want to use this two values to make a sql query in db, and the result showed in a table.
I can't get this to work, solutions needed

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alter how a submission is rendered, for example adding a table, you need to implement [hook_webform_submission_render_alter()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_webform_submission_render_alter/7). The hook receive the data for the submission in `$renderable['#submission']`, and the node in `$renderable['#node']`.

An example of `hook_webform_submission_render_alter()` is [webform_webform_submission_render_alter()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/webform_webform_submission_render_alter/7), which contains the following code.

```
function webform_webform_submission_render_alter(&$renderable) {
  // If displaying a submission to end-users who are viewing their own
  // submissions (and not through an e-mail), do not show hidden values.
  // This needs to be implemented at the level of the entire submission, since
  // individual components do not get contextual information about where they
  // are being displayed.
  $node = $renderable['#node'];
  $is_admin = webform_results_access($node);
  if (empty($renderable['#email']) && !$is_admin) {
    // Find and hide the display of all hidden components.
    foreach ($node->webform['components'] as $cid => $component) {
      if ($component['type'] == 'hidden') {
        $parents = webform_component_parent_keys($node, $component);
        $element = &$renderable;
        foreach ($parents as $pid) {
          $element = &$element[$pid];
        }
        $element['#access'] = FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The purpose of [hook_webform_submission_insert()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/7) is inserting the submitted data in a database. You can use that hook to save the data in a database, and show those data in a page rendered from your module, but `hook_webform_submission_insert()` is not thought to render any data.
To make a paragon, `hook_webform_submission_insert()` is equivalent to `hook_node_insert()` that is invoked when a new node is saved, but that should not render any page.

Comment: this `function modsubmit_webform_submission_render_alter(&$renderable) { $node = $renderable['#node']; drupal_set_message(t('Saved @title.',$node)); }` isn't print anything.

Comment: Are you editing an enabled module? If that is the case, Drupal caches the hooks implemented from the modules, and it doesn't notice a module has been modified, if the module is not first disabled, and then re-enabled. `hook_webform_submission_render_alter()` is the hook you should use if you want to alter how a submission is rendered.